# laravel created_at incorrect timezone at save

Tags: php, laravel

i want to save data with my timezone for created_at field

this is save data code looks like :

```
$booking = new Booking();
$booking->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$booking-save();
```

i have set the timezone in `config/app.php` to my timezone

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Jakarta',
```

but it's still incorrect time in database, it's still using UTC time, anyone can help?

Comment: Probably laravel will add the offset on read.Dates are stored usually as utc but the offset will be added later so in case you change the timezone it will be easy to do.

Comment: no, i do select query and it's still with incorrect timezone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please give a try by executing

```
php artisan config:cache
```